# CSS : a:visited not showing properly by Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I have the CSS below set for links. This code generates this..

In Firefox : The links are grey, focus & hover white, but don't turn pink after visitation.

In Safari : The links are grey, focus & hover white, turn to pink when visited but won't reset back to grey after refresh/empty cache/reset safari.

```
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}           
a:link {
  color: grey;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: pink;
}
a:focus {
  color: white;
}
a:active, 
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Help please ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

In Firefox, go to Tools -> Options -> Content (tab) -> Colors-> and check "Allow pages to choose their own color." That should allow you to see your CSS visited color.

Possibly the correct order isn't used:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
a:focus
```

Order your code like this:

```
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}           
a:link {
  color: grey;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: pink;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer to include changes to Preferences: In Firefox, go to Tools -> Options -> Content (tab) -> Colors-> and check "Allow pages to choose their own color." That should allow you to see your CSS visited color.

Comment: Just checked that and it's already set to "allow pages to choose their own color".